# how to write Junit test case for date to string formatter method?

Tags: junit, junit4

Is this the right way to write a junit test case for the below method:

```
public static String formatDate(Date date) {

        String str = null;

        if(date == null){

            str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        }
        else{
            str = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
        }

        return str;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFormatDate() {
        Date date = new Date();
        String actualDate = DateUtils.formatDate(date);
        System.out.println(actualDate);
        assertEquals(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss").format(date), actualDate);

    }
```

For me the way the expected date is setup feels wrong. what you say?

Comment: do you have any problem with the code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with your test. As long as the expected date format match with the one in the implementation. That's the assertion goal to be tested.

I would only suggest a few refactoring to be nicer

```
public static String formatDate(Date date) {
    Date dateToBeFormatted = date != null ? date : new Date();
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss").format(dateToBeFormatted);
}

/* Assume the below code block in a separate test file  */
@Test
public void testFormatDate() {
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(actualDate);

    String expectedDateFormat = "yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss";
    String expectedResult = generateExpectedDateWithFormat(expectedDateFormat, date);

    String actualDate = DateUtils.formatDate(date);
    assertEquals(expectedResult, actualDate);
}

private String generateExpectedDateWithFormat(String dateFormat, Date date) {
    return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).format(date)
}
```